Thoughts about "StackDesk" app that I am developing
As a developer, I've often found certain features on Stack Overflow challenging to use. After discussing these difficulties with fellow developers, they shared similar experiences. This led me to create StackDesk, a desktop app designed to help developers overcome these issues.
 Expected features include: 
 Bookmark questions & answers without logging in – It's challenging to bookmark content on Stack Overflow without an account, so this feature aims to solve that.
 Watch for (combination) tags – Developers find it difficult to follow questions based on specific tag combinations. This feature will allow for better monitoring.
 Get notified of question activity – Keeping track of updates or activities on specific questions can be tough, and StackDesk will notify developers of any relevant changes.
 Access your notifications – Developers often miss important notifications on Stack Overflow. This feature ensures that updates are always visible and easy to access.
I'd love to hear your thoughts or feedback on this https://github.com/ak2403/stackdesk/issues/1 to understand if StackDesk could be helpful for developers. 
You can also check https://stackdesk.netlify.app/
(P.S.: It's the same info as you see here...I didn't think it through while creating the website )
